# Ubuntu MultiMonitor - 4K and HD

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I am trying to set up a second monitor on my system which is running ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  My first monitor is a 39" 4K display (running at 30hz), which works fine and is what I'm typing this on.  The seconday monitor I've been trying to setup is a 32" HD TV VIZIO 32-Inch Class D-Series Full-Array LED.  I'm trying to set it up vertically mostly for reading reference material while I work.  My graphics card appears to be a cape verde pro radeon hd 7750.

However, when I go to Screen Display in the System Settings menu, and turn the 32" HD monitor on (and rotated) my 39" monitor seems to stop responding to input (i.e. if I click a launchpad item it will not launch).

My question is, would this be related to my hardware (i.e. do I have the horsepower to run these two monitors simultaneously?  and how would I know this?)  or is there something that I need to setup specifically?

Comment: hm. Happen to have another system handy? SSHing in might let you run command line things to check processor usage and the like even if the gui is not responsive.

Comment: I do have ssh handy from my phone... how should I check that?

Comment: top/htop for system stuff. Tools for GPU may vary http://askubuntu.com/questions/387594/how-to-measure-gpu-usage sounds like a good place to start